# How to make text relative to background using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, text

I have made it so that my background image scales to fit the size of the viewport. Now, I want the text to scale relative to the background image. Note: I am using the `<img>` tag for the background image because this allows for scaling with smaller browser windows (i.e., mobile devices).

CSS

```
img.bg
{
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width; 781;

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 781)
{
    img.bg
    {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -390.5;
    }
}

#container 
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 781;
    height: 758;
    border: 1px solid black
    z-index: 2;
}

#left
{   
    position: relative;
    left: 1.280409731113956%;
    top: 14.51187335092348%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}   

p
{
    font: 14px Georgia;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

HTML

```
<img class="bg" src="background.jpg">

<div id="container">
<div id="left">
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the font size to increase/decrease?

Comment: Yes, but aligned with the background and in the format I set it up to be in.

Comment: If you set up your text sizes using percentages or EMs it will automatically scale. WOrth a shot but may not do exactly what you're wanting it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't scale text dynamically in this way with css alone as far as I know.

you might be able to do it with jQuery if you make the selected font-size proportional to window.innerWidth using something like this.

```
function resizeText(event) {
       //your text element
       var $text = $('h2');

       if(window.innerWidth <= 781){

           //font scaling ratio
           var  fontSize = window.innerWidth/100;             
           $text.css('font-size', fontSize+'px');   

       } else {
           $text.css('');
       }
}

  //run above on window load and resize events
  window.onresize = resizeText;
  window.onload = resizeText;
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with using jQuery. What exactly do I do with that above code?

Comment: jQuery is a common javascript library the documentation is here http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing all your text or just headings? You might want to look into "Fittex" or "Bigtext".

You can do it with strictly using CSS and Media Queries.

I also saw another method on here a few days ago with someone's method to do it strictly with CSS and without media queries.

Also check out this post:
[Is it possible to dynamically scale text size based on browser width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358183/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-scale-text-size-based-on-browser-width)

Comment: Please provide a better context for "Fittex" or "Bigtext". Are they CSS properties, JS libraries, we don't know... a link would be much more helpful.