# Set type size in relation to parent's width

Tags: jquery, css, typography

I'm creating a website with a design which aims to fill the screen. As a result the elements' dimensions are percentage based.

I have a sidebar with a width of `30%` of the browser window (I've set this with css)

Now I want the text to fit in this sidebar, and be *as large as possible*.

How do I make the the font size dependent on the sidebar's width? Is this possible with only CSS, or would I need to use jQuery?

Let me know if you need any more info, thanks for your help already!

Comment: I've been really impressed by this plugin for this type of thing: http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a little jQuery is necessary. Check out this answer on a similar question: [Is it possible to dynamically scale text size based on browser width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358183/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-scale-text-size-based-on-browser-width)