# Bootstrap Fixed navbar, sticky footer, dynamically scaled content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to achieve [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/) but with the difference that in case there is **too much** content on my page (between navbar and footer) that this content is **down-scaled** / squeezed to fit inside (i.e. so that the footer is still visible at all screen resolutions, making it a "fixed footer" in CSS jargon). I'm using bootstrap 3.1.1 and it would be cool if anyone has a solution that is bootstrap-friendly :). Best!

Comment: So you want the content to zoom out / scale rather than allowing it to scroll?

Comment: That's exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 1):

You could always go with a fixed footer and have any additional content scroll underneath it.
Heres a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eh62B/) as an example:

```
html { 
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem /* or whatever your fixed footer height is */
 }

/* and assuming your footer has id="footer"  */
#footer { 
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   height: 1.5rem;
   overflow: hidden;
   }
```

Comment: That's already a good point, thanks. Any ideas, though, how to have the text div to be scaled down to fit exactly right into the remaining space?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358183/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-scale-text-size-based-on-browser-width), and the example it refers to [here](http://www.spookandpuff.com/examples/dynamicTextSize.html).  It's going to be a bit different I assume if you've got pictures and everything though.  If you could provide an example of your content on jsFiddle we could probably help you scale it a little better.

Comment: That solution uses JS. So to me it seems that doing that in just CSS isn't possible. In either case, the example addresses the whole body, while I am wondering whether this technique can be applied to just one particular div.