# css calc function: How to calculate width of text?

Tags: css

Let's say that I have the following html template:

```
<div id="container">
   <h2> Name </h2> <input type="text">
</div>
```

and I want that the width of 'input' will be equal to the width of container - the width of text inside 'h2'. How can I do it?

Comment: If the contents of `h2` are dynamic, you can't do this in CSS directly; you can use [LESS](http://lesscss.org) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide) CSS systems to do this.

Comment: They're not dynamic

Comment: In addition you can use JavaScript if you don't want using a css preprocessor -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Comment: Why can't the ``h2`` not just be a label?

Comment: It can be a label.

Comment: How wide is your `#container`? Does it have a pre-defined width? If you have, you can simply use flexbox so that the input can take up whatever space that is left unoccupied.

Comment: There is no way to use calc() to take the width of text element ?

Answer (score 1):

If the contents of `H2` are dynamic, you can't do this in CSS directly; however, you can use [LESS](http://lesscss.org) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide) CSS implementation systems to do this.

If the contents of `H2` are fairly static, you can do this by setting the size of `H2` (and `input`) as being relative parts of the container:

```
#container {
    width  : 100%;
}
#container > h2, #container > input {
    width       :50%;
    display     :inline-block;
    overflow    :hidden;
    box-sizing  :border-box;
    margin      :0;
}
#container > h2 {
    margin      :2rem 0;
    text-align  :center;
}
#container > input {
    padding     :0.2rem;
}
```

The above (cruddy) example sets the size of the **title text *container*** rather than the text itself; you can manually set the size of the text youself or use some sort of [**Javascript Text Scaling**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358183/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-scale-text-size-based-on-browser-width), of which there are several.

But you need to bear in mind that different browsers will set a whole lot of slightly different settings (especially on inputs) so you will need to ***normalize*** this all as well.

Another solution is to use [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Which will do the same sort of thing; but will reference the size of an element (`input`) on the corresponding elements (`h2`) *box sizing* **NOT** the actual text sizing within the box.

---

Overall. Use LESS or SASS. This is pretty much the future of CSS development. Get on board.

Comment: "however, you can use LESS or SASS CSS implementation systems to do this" Can you explain how or give a link to those parts of their documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Use display and position, input will take 100% width of parent:

```
 h2{
  display:inline-block;
}
div{
  display:inline-block;
    position: relative
}
input{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qzar1we9/

Answer (score 0):

you need `javascript` for that

```
document.getElementById("yourDiv").clientWidth; // returns number, like 728
```

or

```
document.getElementById("yourDiv").offsetWidth;
```

you can get width of `h2` and `container` using this.

calculate and add the width to your `input`

```
document.getElementById('input').setAttribute("style","width:500px");
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap `input` inside a `div` with `overflow-x: hidden` , give `float: left` to `h2` and `width: 100%` to `input`

```css
h2 { 
  float:left;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.fieldOccupyingRemaining {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <h2> Name </h2>
   <div class="fieldOccupyingRemaining">
       <input type="text">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do it with css only, but works only with chrome:

```
#container{
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

h2,input{
  display:inline;
}


input {
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  position: absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t8a44sn5/2/

I know this is not a valid answer for now, but in future can be. http://caniuse.com/#search=fill-available

Answer (score 0):

Use the Below Code for it

```
span{
display:inline-block;
width:180px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow:hidden !important;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5vpb/)